# How to create button in a loop and assign each button a specific tag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i want to create a cluster of buttons.for this i am using a loop like this.

```
for (int i =0; i< [plistArray count];i++) {

    editButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width-10, -3.6, 39, 35)];
    [editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DeleteButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteObjectViewImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

but when i clicked on any random button assigned function is not called.It called when i clicked first button(in a sequence 1,2,3).

Comment: do you want to dynamically add buttons on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one:

```
    #define ButtonHeight 40

    #define OffsetBetweenButtons 20

    #define ButtonHeightPlusOffsetBetweenButtons (ButtonHeight+OffsetBetweenButtons)

//create 6 buttons from 0,1,2,3,4,5 so totally 6 buttons
for(int buttonIndex=0;buttonIndex<=5;buttonIndex++){

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DeleteButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Set offset in Y axis
    button.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, ButtonHeightPlusOffsetBetweenButtons * buttonIndex , 280.0, 40.0);

    //Set Tag for future identification
    [button setTag:buttonIndex];

    [YourView addSubview:button];

}
```

Comment: To explain why I down-voted this answer: you've provided no explanation for the code or anything on _why_ this is your answer, it's just a bunch of code with some magic numbers (and inconsistent use of constants via macros). In other words, I don't think this is an answer so much as someone just straight up writing the code for the asker. Also don't like your username and the self-promotion via the button title — so I downvoted for that too.

Comment: @nil Thanks for your interest on my answer and i would like to answer your question  

1.why did i use macros here 

 Stock over flow is not only for Expert/Experience developers. The question can be visited by anyone. So Here i can simply put the 60 as value instead of those macros. 
 
 But any programmers can understand by seeing that macros.
 
 Objective C is very descriptive language, which will specify the purpose of the method by method name.

Comment: @nil 2. You had specified like i did self promote. I didn't intend for it. Even though you had specified that as it was, i have removed that. Remember that you could also edit the answer.

Comment: I think you've tried to dodge the issue of the answer just being _bad_ overall, so the down-vote remains.